# Backup SQL Server database on UNC path using SA

Tags: sql-server

We need to backup some database to an unc path, the problem it's that it's a SQL Server instance that has to execute with SQL Server autentication (`sa` user).

How can we configure the plan task in SQL Server to make it able to have access to the UNC folder? I attach the state of our SQL Server Services in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Thanks in advance and regards,

Pedro Sánchez.

[image]

Comment: Are you using UNC path to copy the backups over Network on to other server? If yes does that server has SQL installed?

Comment: Hi Kapil, the source server, evidently have installed the SQL, in fact it's when we have the BBDD that have to be copied. And really, the remote destination it's a NAS where we have prepare a shared folder. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Can you not just use the full network path?  Why does it have to be mapped to a drive?  We do something similar here but i just backup to `\\backups\prod` and it's fine.

Comment: Hi Kris, we've tried using the entire UNC path but the incident persists.

Answer (score 3):

You can map a local drive letter to your UNC folder using xp_cmdshell like:
exec xp_cmdshell 'net use X: \MyServer\MySharedFolder\'

Then you can issue your backup statement to use the X: drive as if it was local.

You may have to run sp_configure to enable xp_cmdshell.

Comment: Just adding to the already correct answer, here's a step by step of how to do just that: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3499/make-network-path-visible-for-sql-server-backup-and-restore-from-within-ssms/

Comment: Also worth mentioning that enabling xp_cmdshell poses a security risk so use caution.

Comment: Hi Queue, as Kris mentioned it's a high risk for the server security enable the xp_cmdshell :(

Comment: Yes it is.  The Surface Area Configuration will usually have it disabled by default.  That sort of ties into the whole sa account because whoever has sysadmin privileges on your instance has, in effect, the same domain privileges as the Windows account that the SQL Server service runs under.